Whats the difference between 二度も and 二度と?
What's the difference between 二度と and 二度も?
E.g. こんな奇跡は二度もない and こんな奇跡は二度とない?

If I'm not mistaken, the "も" here (used after a counter) is supposed to give the sense that something is a significantly large quantity.
For example, "私{わたし}は一度{いちど}銃{じゅう}に打{う}たれた" (I was shot once by a gun) vs "私{わたし}は三度{さんど}も銃{じゅう}に打{う}たれた" (I was shot 3 times by a gun [and that's a lot]). The も here implies that 3 times is quite a lot to have been shot.
In your example, も would imply that 2 miracles is quite a lot (and isn't going to happen). Whereas just 二度とない is just stating that it's not going to happen again.

二度とない is a very common idiom meaning a rare event that could never happen twice. It expresses that the rare event occurred, and is expected to never occur again.
On the other hand, こんな奇跡は二度もない sounds peculiar, it’s not something you would hear people say, unless mistakenly intending to say 二度とない。
If it really was intended to be 二度もない, it seems like it would describe a rare occurrence that did happen twice, and expresses disbelief that it really did happen under normal circumstances.
二度とない -> This will never happen again (after it happened once).
二度もない -> This happened twice, but that’s impossible. (Am I mistaken? Was there cheating?)
